# How can we replace value in unix using sed after a certain pattern

Tags: shell, unix

I Have a file with below data, in which I want to replace everything in line after a `Default nextval` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`

I tries sed command but it didn't help
Data:

```
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(`xchange_finance`.`seq_cancelled_contract_zendesk_publishing_failure`),
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(`xchange_finance`.`seq_invoice`),
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(`xchange_finance`.`seq_invoice_attachment`),
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(`xchange_finance`.`seq_invoice_line_item`),
```

expected:

```
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

tried something like below but it didn't work
`sed -e 's/^DEFAULT nextval.*$/AUTO_INCREMENT ,/g' test`

Comment: `s/^DEFAULT...` will match the word DEFAULT only at the beginning of the line.  You should omit the `^` to match it elsewhere.

Comment: thanks @WilliamPursell I tried to remove`^` but it is still the same.

```sed -e 's/DEFAULT nextval$/AUTO_INCREMENT/g' test```

Comment: worked like this 
`sed -e 's/DEFAULT.*/AUTO_INCREMENT/g'`